# How do I pass a search parameter to URL?

Tags: angular, typescript, http, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I created a method in asp.net core web api that returns me an object which contains the string I pass in the URL.

Now I have a search form that should send that string to the URL and return me the objects that contain it.

This is how I consume the api:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { ContactDetail } from "./contact-detail.model";
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class ContactDetailService {
  formData: ContactDetail;
  readonly rootURL = "http://localhost:60809/api";
  list: ContactDetail[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

 // search contacts
  searchContactDetail(keyword: string) {
    return this.http
      .get(this.rootURL + "/ContactDetail/Search/" + keyword)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => (this.list = res as ContactDetail[]));
  }
```

This is the search form:

```html
<form
      class="form-inline"
      #form="ngForm"
      autocomplete="off"
      (submit)="searchContact(keyword)"
    >
      <input
        name="keyword"
        class="form-control mr-sm-2"
        type="search"
        placeholder="Search"
        aria-label="keyword"
      />
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
```

And how I send the string:

```js
 searchContact(keyword: string) {
    this.service.searchContactDetail(keyword);
  }
```

Also the form and the table that returns the result are not in the same component if that matters.

What I get now when I search it sends the rootURL/search/undefined. So whatever I type it sends undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you've inserted the wrong parameter in `form.(submit)`.

Change this:

```
<form
  class="form-inline"
  #form="ngForm"
  autocomplete="off"
  (submit)="searchContact(keyword)"
>

  <input
    name="keyword"
    class="form-control mr-sm-2"
    type="search"
    placeholder="Search"
    aria-label="keyword"
    />
```

To this:

```
<form
  class="form-inline"
  autocomplete="off"
  (ngSubmit)="searchContact(keyword.value)"
>

  <input
    name="keyword"
    class="form-control mr-sm-2"
    type="search"
    placeholder="Search"
    aria-label="keyword"
    #keyword
    />
```

What I did was:

1. Changing the `(submit)` event to `(ngSubmit)` which sort-of prevents from the browser the default behavior of submitting a get request.
2. binding a variable named `keyboard` to the `input[name="keyword"]` and then passing its value in `ngSubmit`.

A working example - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-f8s8zf

Comment: Yes, this actually sends the keyword, but the url is wrong. It looks like this: http://localhost:4200/?keyword=somekeyword instead of http://localhost:4200/ContactDetails/search/keyword

Comment: It shouldn't reload. If it does, it may be caused by an error. Do you see an error in the console before it reloads? In any case, did you import `FormsModule` in your module?

Comment: I get ERROR TypeError: "_co.event is undefined". I imported FormsModule in my app.module yes.

Comment: @Antoniusz I'm sorry I mislead you. Please review my answer again.